# Prototyping method

Tags: pins, wires, prototype

I'm currently using a normal breadbord 'n' solid-core-wires for prototyping, but it gets messy when I need to connect a large number of pins on the arduino, as when using an LCD display + another sensor. What are my other options for prototyping?

Comment: The real strength of an Arduino is shields. Ironically, that's also its biggest weakness.

Comment: After seeing pictures of shields and shields on top of each other, I really wanted to stay away from stacking things as possible i can

Comment: Use a protoshield like: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoProtoShield or make your own out of protoboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the Arduino's greatest strengths are shields, and shields upon shields. (Another is it's ease of programming via USB amongst a whole host of others).

They are perfect for prototyping. There's nothing wrong with breadboarding it as well, but it's pretty much one or the other (excluding making your own circuit board).

I am working on a garage controller and it has three shields on top of the arduino itself.

1. XBee/wireless coms
2. a relay shield, and
3. a prototying shield where I have created custom circuitry (buttons, connectors, optocouplers etc).

Especially with the top shield, I have made several changes to get it to perform as I'd like. If I'd committed to making a custom board, then I would have had to change it (and re-change it). What I've done would be virtually impossible on a breadboard.

The idea is, you use the shields to get your idea up and running, as a proof of concept. Then, you could/can leave it as is, or you could take the next step, break it down to the required components and make a custom PCB for your project. If it wasn't for shields and stacking shields, you would either breadboard it (which as you've indicated can get ugly, cumbersome and problematic), or make a PCB which (depending on the project) might not be a small task. So shield it up, test it out, then build your own based on what you've put together.

That's not to say, you have to make your own PCB in the end, many projects can remain a shield on an arduino. So if you can find a shield to do specifically what you're after, then why wouldn't you use it?